# Create diagram of a channel coding problem

Tags: diagrams

How can I create the following diagram?

[image]

Additionally, I want under the "Channel" box a flash to show channel interference/noise to clarify that Y is corrupted by noise.

Comment: I realize it's hard to search for things like this, but here are a couple of (slightly more complex) examples that might get you started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163481/specific-box-diagram-with-multiple-arrows https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167278/how-to-position-in-tikz-relatively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `tikz`:

**Edit:**
ok., with added red lightning:
**One more edit:**
now is added text to lightning. Since this text is unknow, correct one is left to you ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,   % new
                positioning,
                quotes,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 18mm, % <---
  start chain = going right,
   box/.style = {draw, thick,
                 minimum height=9mm, minimum width =18mm,
                 on chain},
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, semithick},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, align=center},
                        ]
\coordinate[on chain] (in);
\node (n1) [box]    {Encoder};
\node (n2) [box, 
            label={[font=\Huge, text=red]:\Lightning}]    {Channel};
            \node[above=of n2, font=\footnotesize] {To je strela!}; % <---
\node (n3) [box]    {Decoder};
\coordinate[on chain] (out);
%
\path   (in) edge ["Message\\ $\mathcal{K}$"]      (n1)
        (n1) edge ["Codeword\\ $X_{\mathcal{K}}$"] (n2)
        (n2) edge ["Output\\ $Y$"]                  (n3)
        (n3) edge ["Estimate\\ $\widehat{\mathcal{K}}$"]   (out);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please add a flash under the noise box to denote interference in the channel?

Comment: @wayne, how should looks "flash"?

Comment: Something like the red flash on the following page: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/realworld/reedsolomon/reed_solomon_codes.html

Comment: @wayne, see edited answer.

Comment: You are the best! Thanks! how can I add text above the lightning?

Comment: @wayne, added. But, your recent request is so simple that you should manage it yourself ;-) . I strongly encourage you to read some introductory text about LaTeX and Ti*k*Z. For example "The not so short  introduction to LaTeX2e" and "Minimal introduction to TikZ (unofficial)". Both you can find by googling.

Comment: I will do. Thanks for the references

Answer (score 4):

I propose this solution with basic tools (packages amsmath, eqparbox & stackengine):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{geometry} 

\begin{document}

\[ \xrightarrow{\eqparbox{L}{\bfseries\boldmath\Centerstack{Message \\ $\mathcal{K}$}}} \eqframebox[C]{\enspace Encoder\enspace }
\xrightarrow{\eqparbox{L}{\bfseries\boldmath \Centerstack{Codeword \\$\textsf{X}_\mathcal{K}$}}}\eqframebox[C]{Channel}
 \xrightarrow{\eqparbox{L}{\bfseries\boldmath \Centerstack{Output \\ Y}}}\eqframebox[C]{Decoder}
  \xrightarrow{\eqparbox{L}{\bfseries\boldmath \Centerstack{Estimate \\$\hat{\mathcal{K}}$}}}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]